# React: UseState save previous state of object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a movie form like this:

[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziHhh.png)

When I click Add Moview button a function is invoked that is supposed to save all the three parameters into the object, but problem is that previous values get overwritten.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const myPrevState = newMovie;
    setNewMovie({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
    console.log(newMovie);
  };
```

Can anyone help me in solving this problem? I want my setNewMovie object to contain the following values (Please refer to image)

```
{
  name: Entered Movie Name,
  rating: Entered Movie Rating
  duration: Entered Movie duration
}
```

My initial state is defined as follows:

```
const [newMovie, setNewMovie] = useState({
    name: "",
    ratings: "",
    duration: "",
  });
```

**Update**

Error I get after using callback:

```
setNewMovie((o) => ({ ...o, [e.target.id]: e.target.value }));
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfmUR.png)

Comment: Unfortunately it gave me an error just after I started typing the value. Can you please have a look? I updated the post.

Comment: "problem is that previous values get overwritten" -- can you elaborate what you meant by that? Is your form getting reset? If that's the case then you just need to call `e.preventDefault` in your submit handler. Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mc78oq

Comment: newMovie object contain three values, name, duration and ratings. When my original statement executes it clears the object and save only the currently active value inside the object.

Comment: any update? I am running into same problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume you are using an older version of React that pools its events and (*generally*) quickly nullifies the event objects after the callback has completed executing. The issue is that in React that enqueued state updates are asynchronously processed. The event object has been nullified and properties such as `e.target` are inaccessible because the event object is null.

To resolve you can cache the `id` and `value` properties in scope so they are saved and accessible when React updates the state. Don't forget that in function components the `useState` hook's updater function ***doesn't*** shallowly merge state so you need to handle this manually.

Example;

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { id, value } = e.target; // <-- save event id and value

  setNewMovie(state => ({
    ...state,    // <-- shallow copy previous state
    [id]: value, // <-- update property by dynamic key
  }));
};
```